# Format TimeSpan in 12-hour format with AM/PM in MVC Model and View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timespan, time-format

I have an MVC webpage contains a StartTime timepicker, so I want to view and save that time in 12-hour format with AM/PM. I've tried to format the TimeSpan in the Model and the View as shown below, but it doesn't work and shows "Input string was not in a correct format." error in the View. What should I do?

In Model:

```
public class Model
{
    .
    .
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm\\:tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    .
    .
}
```

In View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartTime, "{0:hh\\:mm\\:tt}")
```

Comment: You cannot. `tt` is not a valid format string for `TimeSpan`  (only for `DateTime`)

Comment: You could create an extension method to generate the output, but then you would also need to write a custom ModelBinder to bind the value back to `TimeSpan`

Comment: @StephenMuecke So, How to display it (AM/PM) in TimeSpan?

Comment: See the 2nd comment. Unless your doing this a lot (to make the effort of creating extension methods, a jquery plugin and a custom ModelBinder), you would be better off making property DateTime in your view model and then map to and from your data model

Comment: AM/PM makes no logical sense for a TimeSpan. A TimeSpan can be 20 days or -5 milliseconds. You are thinking of a DayTimeOffset but that isn't an existing type.